# How to set Default value in MVC 4 razor DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I Have MVC Razor view with lot of DropDrownFor.
i wanna set default value to that DropdownListFor.

This is my View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DestCountryId, ViewBag.CountryIdList as SelectList, "select", new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
```

This is my ViewBag:

```
 ViewBag.CountryIdList = new SelectList(db.Countries.Where(a => a.Currency != null), "Id", "Name");
```

Ho w to set Default value in this scenario

Comment: try either of the two solutions that I have mentioned in my answer. It should work as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do like this:

```
ViewBag.CountryIdList = new SelectList(db.Countries.Where(a => a.Currency != null), "Id", "Name",1);
```

For Example in the Countries List, you have a item CountryName and its id is 1, you need to pass the 1 in the last parameter, and element with that Id 1 will be shown selected by default.

**Example:**

```
public class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

List<Country> list = new List<Country>();

list.Add(new Country{ Id = 1, Name="Test"});
list.Add(new Country{ Id = 2, Name="Test2"});
```

now in controller action:

```
int Selected = 2;
ViewBag.CountryIdList = new SelectList(list, "Id", "Name",Selected);
```

Now the **Test2** will be shown selected default in View.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter that you give to `@Html.DropDownListFor` is an expression that identifies the object that contains the properties to display.

You have already given "Selected" as default value if nothing is selected or your `DestCountryId` doesn't hold any value or it doesn't matches with the values passed in the `CountryIdList.` You need to assign a value to `DestCountryId` before rendering this view. You can do this either in controller or where you build your view-model like:

`viewModel.DestCountryId = 33;` where this value exists in the selectList value that you are giving to dropdownlist.

Also, a good practise is to not to use ViewBag. Try creating a simple model with properties that your current view needs.

You can also use [SelectList(IEnumerable, String, String, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Web.Mvc.SelectList.#ctor%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true) overload of `SelectList` where the object is the selected value.

Hope this helps.