# IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Is not showing the database stored value

Tags: c#, razor

I have a dropdown list that is not showing the default value in the view. After debugging I can see that the default values are being pulled with the correct values but they are not being displayed. I store my IEnumerable in my ViewModel

Example:
DropDown 1 is supposed to show True (that is the value in the DB) but is showing the first value "Not Set"

[image]

**View**

```
@model IList<NavLiveWebInterface.ViewModel.Proc_Item_SKUViewModel>

    for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => Model[i].Filterable)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model[i].Filterable,Model[i].TrueFalse)
            </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model[i].Filterable,"Please Select a Value")
    }
```

**View Model**

```
public bool? Filterable { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TrueFalse
{
    get
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new SelectListItem { Value = "Not Set", Text = "Not Set" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "True", Text = "True" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "False", Text = "False" }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting DropDownListFor to the value True? How would it know that true is the default?

Comment: What type is `Model[i].Filterable`?

Comment: @Bit It's not really a "default" value its whatever is stored in the db so its either True or false I'll update my question I can see how it could be misleading

Comment: @StevenV `bool?` I'll it to my code

Comment: I wonder if you're running into this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11045737/254973

Comment: This example may help you out I do not think SelectListItems can be used this way: http://forums.asp.net/t/1959753.aspx?Best+way+to+populate+drop+down+lists+MVC+4+razor+

Comment: @StevenV It seems like it, I'm just not sure how to implement it while having my an IList View

Comment: I'm guessing something like this. I'll try it out and let you know. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23287965/how-to-set-default-value-in-mvc-4-razor-dropdownlistfor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DropDownListFor` does not support matching a selected value from an *indexed expression*.

You need to create a `SelectList` for each entry, that has the *current selected value* passed to it.

### This will work:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => Model[i].FilterableString)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model[i].Filterable, new SelectList(Model[i].TrueFalse, "Value", "Text", Model[i].Filterable));
    </div>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model[i].Filterable, "Please Select a Value")
}
```

*You are also repeating the option of a drop-down list. It is only the `SelectList` created from the options that needs to be unique (in order to have a selected state) so you could share a single data list for your `True`, `False` and `null` options and provide it via the `ViewBag` (but don't forget to cast it back to an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` in the `SelectList` constructor or you get an error)*

### Update - Share the list:

You can create a single shared list in the ViewBag like this controller code:

```
ViewBag.Filterable = new List<KeyValuePair<bool?, string>>()
{
    new KeyValuePair<bool?, string>( null, "Not Set" ),
    new KeyValuePair<bool?, string>( true, "True" ),
    new KeyValuePair<bool?, string>( false, "False" )
};
```

I used a `KeyValuePair` as that is really what you are creating for your options.

and you access it in the view like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model[i].Filterable, new SelectList((IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<bool?, string>>)ViewBag.Filterable, "Key", "Value", Model[i].Filterable));
```

### One last word:

If you were not using indexed items, the simpler `@Html.DropDown("Filterable")` would automatically bind the value to the `ViewModel` (e.g. `Model.Filterable`) and the drop down list to a `ViewBag` property of the same name (e.g. `ViewBag.Filterable`). This can come in handy for shorter code in simpler situations.

Comment: Thanks for the response and the code it works great. I'm not 100% sure though on what you mean by "repeating the option of a drop-down list". Are you saying I should use a viewbag instead of having the drop down in my viewmodel?

Comment: Updated with practical example of a shared list. A drop down list never belongs in a single item's model (unless it were unique per item). Hope this does the trick for you :)