# Dropdown not selecting correct value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

what is wrong withe following code?

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.title, new List<SelectListItem>
  {
      new SelectListItem { Text = "Other" , Value = "Other"},
      new SelectListItem { Text = "Mr", Value = "Mr" },
      new SelectListItem { Text = "Mrs", Value = "Mrs" },
      new SelectListItem { Text = "Ms", Value = "Ms" },
      new SelectListItem { Text = "Miss", Value = "Miss" }
    }, 
      new { @class = "form-control" })
```

the above is allowing me to select and save the value to the table, but when it come to edit , the saved value is not selected

for example the existing Data was saved with "Mr" when editing it shows "Other"

why?

Comment: Have you checked what is getting passed in `model.title`?

Comment: yes "Mr"  when i display model.title

Comment: https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=DropDownListFor+selected+value

Comment: @LeBlues - Not while displaying, I am asking when you are binding this View, you must be passing a Model right? In that model what is the value of title?

Comment: If the value of property `title` is "Mr", then the second option will be selected.

Comment: @Rahul Singh is it "Mr" , i am displaying the value from the model in the view

Comment: @Stephen Muecke  it is not, that is what is driving me nuts

Comment: Then there is something else wrong. Add `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.title)` to your view and confirm that its actually rendering "Mr".

Comment: @LeBlues - In that case, I am think your `title` has some white space i.e. it must be "Mr " or " Mr".

Comment: no White space as i select a value from the list 'Mr' and saved it is putting value into the object and getting it back to the view (@Html.DisplayFor) but the dropdown is not selecting

Comment: check this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23287965/how-to-set-default-value-in-mvc-4-razor-dropdownlistfor

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is that this is an `EditorTemplate` and your using `EditorFor()` in a loop?

Comment: @Stephen Muecke what loop? there is no loop

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. The code you have shown WILL select the correct option so there is some other issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay

i found the issue

you cannot have "title" as the name. title is a property on HTML5. i renamed the field to dTitle and it works

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`SelectList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) with [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn725507%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) following way:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.title, new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>
  {
      new SelectListItem { Text = "Other" , Value = "Other"},
      new SelectListItem { Text = "Mr", Value = "Mr" },
      new SelectListItem { Text = "Mrs", Value = "Mrs" },
      new SelectListItem { Text = "Ms", Value = "Ms" },
      new SelectListItem { Text = "Miss", Value = "Miss" }
    },
    "Value",
    "Text",
     Model.Title), 
     new { @class = "form-control" })
```

> > SelectList Constructor (IEnumerable, String, String, String, Object)

```
public SelectList(
    IEnumerable items,
    string dataValueField,
    string dataTextField,
    string dataGroupField,
    Object selectedValue
)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is worst

it is working in this cause but not the one above

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PreferredContact, new List<SelectListItem>
                                            {
                                            new SelectListItem { Text = "Other" },
                                            new SelectListItem { Text = "Telephone", Value = "Telephone" } ,
                                            new SelectListItem { Text = "Email", Value = "Email" },
                                            new SelectListItem { Text = "Post", Value = "Post" }
                                            }, new { @class = "form-control" })
```