# MVC5 Html.DropDownListFor Does not select correct value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm doing something horribly simple and it isn't working.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ContentDefinitionID, Model.ContentBoxesSelectList, new {@class = "form-control"})
```

The `ContentDefinitionID` is a `UInt64` (although I've tried an int)

I use this same select list for 4 different controls on the page.

If my `Model.ContentDefinition` is set to 4, (which would be `test4` in the drop down) then it SHOULD pull that selected value from the Model, NOT from the `selectList` right?  Someone else said that it ignores the value on the `SelectList` when you use the `m=>m.X` syntax - which makes sense.

But it always selects the first one.  I tried adding another parameter for what it should select, but it wants the text, not the value and I hate to have to lookup the text.  (And I'm not sure this will post back correctly if I do that anyway)

I'm about to go create some JQuery code to set the default values for everything -but that is crazy.  This is the obvious behavior of the `DropDownListFor()` method, kind of a 'duh' thing - why doesn't it work?   Do I need to create a custom `SelectList` for every control that exists on the page?

--- Update, the model etc:

```
class PageModel
   {
   Int64 ContentDefinitionID {get;set;}
   SelectList ContentBoxesSelectList {get;set;}
   }

Controller init for model:

 model.ContentDefinitionID = 4;   // In real situation, this is an
 array of N model.ContentBoxesSelectList = new SelectList( from
 ContentDefinitionDocument doc in allContentBoxes
             where doc.Size == size
             select new {Name = doc.Name, id = doc.DefinitionID}, "Id", "Name");
```

Rendered Output (from it as an array):

```
            selected value should be: 1

            <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ContentDefinitionID must be a number." data-val-required="The ContentDefinitionID field is required." id="ContentBoxes_0__ContentDefinitionID" name="ContentBoxes[0].ContentDefinitionID" style="width:25%;float:left"><option value="1">Test1</option>
   <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="4">Test 4</option>
    <option value="0">Test 0</option>
    </select>
```

And None of them are selected.

Comment: You have to pass selected value in SelectList, can you show your action where you populate model?

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23287965/how-to-set-default-value-in-mvc-4-razor-dropdownlistfor

Comment: The problem is that I have ONE select list, and n drop downs that all have the same set of items that can be selected.   It seems (and seems like it should) ignore the default value in the SelectList if it is mapped to a model field.  (this was specifically stated in another StackOverflow about why the default wasn't getting used from the SelectList)

Comment: BTW: The last comment in the post you give above is exactly what I want to work.  Set the value in the model, and have it show that item as selected.

Comment: It works if I create N SelectLists - one for each call to DropDownListFor() - with the default value specified in the List.  Seems like a horrible waste to me.   And seems like the SelectList shouldn't be able to specify the default value correctly if you are binding to a field - is it would use the value of the field and not the value in the SelectList.

Comment: Change `Model.ContentBoxesSelectList` from a property to a function that accepts a "selected item".  Pass in `m.ContentDefinitionID`, and have the function return an instance of the list, with the correct value selected.  You can store the initial list privately in the model, and return a copy with the correct value selected.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing for today :-(  I have a function that will generate a new select list from the original source data and set the selected item.  However, this seems bad - not only does it duplicate the list N times it should be able to work without it.  I would be happy if there was just a DropDownFor() method that accepted the default value not the default displayed text.

Comment: Then create SelectList in View just before passing to helper

Comment: @TraderhutGames you can write your owm helper as well.

Comment: @TraderhutGames I have posted what I mean to say

Answer (score 2):

From the html your generating (`name="ContentBoxes[0].ContentDefinitionID"`), you are using this in a `for` loop. Unfortunately `DropDownListFor()` does not work as expected in a `for` loop and you need to use a custom `EditorTemplate` for your model (its been reported as a bug but not yet fixed).

You have not posted your models, but assuming

```
public class ContentBox
{
  public int ContentDefinitionID { get; set; }
  ....
}

public class ContentBoxesVM
{
  public IEnumerable<ContentBox> ContentBoxes { get; set; }
  public SelectList ContentBoxesSelectList { get; set; }
}
```

Side note: Its only necessary to generate one `SelectList` (rather that one for each object in the collection)

Controller

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
  ContentBoxesVM model = new ContentBoxesVM();
  // populate model, for example
  model.ContentBoxes = new List<ContentBox>()
  {
    new ContentBox { ContentDefinitionID = 4 }
  };
  model.ContentBoxesSelectList = new SelectList(...);
  return View(model);
}
```

Editor Template (`/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/ContentBox.cshtml`)

```
@model ContentBox
....
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ContentDefinitionID, (SelectList)ViewData["contentBoxesList"])
...
```

Main view

```
@model ContentBoxesVM
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  ....
  // pass the select list as additional view data to the editor template
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ContentBoxes, new { contentBoxesList = Model.ContentBoxesSelectList })
  ....
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

Comment: So the only change that I had was yes, it is a List<ContentBox>  And Yes, I use a for loop (even tried using a var to avoid the closure problem)  the ONLY issue I have with it is the selected value not being set.  It works perfectly fine if I call a function to create a new list for each SelectList.   Is the lack of setting the correct selected item the reported defect that you are referring to?

Comment: In your example, the Main View would need to do EditorFor(m=>m.ContentBoxes[n],... Would it not?  I mean, if you are passing in all of them does it create the EditorTemplate for each of them in the list?  (I've not used EditorTemplates yet.)  If so, that sounds pretty cool.  Also, do the EditorTemplates have anything special about them other than the Model matching?  Do they have to be in the 'Shared/EditorTemplates' directory?  (This would muddy things up for my system as we have folders under the View directory for each Controller and would like all of that view there.)

Comment: Yes, Its a bug (at least I consider it one). If used in a `for` loop the first option will always be selected no matter what the value of the property is, which is why you need to use an `EditorTemplate` (which will select the correct option based on the value of the property)

Comment: No. It just needs to be `EditorFor(m=>m.ContentBoxes)` otherwise you will have exactly the same problem you are having now (and in fact it probably wont even bind because it will not name the controls correctly with indexers). The `EditorFor()` method is smart enough to be able to render a collection properly.

Comment: The only conventions is that they need to be located in `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplate` (can be accessed from any view) or `/Views/YourController/EditorTemplates` (can be accessed only from a view associated with the controller - which allows you to have multiple implementations) and that the name must match the class name (in your case `ContentBox.cshtml`)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by changing your model:

```
class PageModel 
{ 
 Int64 ContentDefinitionID {get;set;} 
 List<ContentDefinitionDocument> ContentBoxesList {get;set;} 
}
```

and in controller:

```
array of N model.ContentBoxesList = allContentBoxes.Where(doc => doc.Size == size).ToList();
```

and in View create `SelectList` this way:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ContentDefinitionID,
                           new SelectList(Model.ContentBoxesSelectList,
                                          "DefinitionID",
                                          "Name",
                                          Model.ContentDefintionID),
                      new {@class = "form-control"})
```